# DB2 stored proc with Out param always NULL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

This is DB2 on the IBM I.

I use Run SQL Scripts to test my SP.
[image]

I even tried to initialize the out parameter as follows and got the same result...

```
CALL SGDEDMGT.USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM(
  BLAHNO => 'xx#########00000####',  
  /* IN  CHARACTER(20)    */
  BLAHID => '0'   /* OUT INTEGER          */
);
```

This is the result I get back...

```
 [ 09/09/2022, 03:45:30 PM ]  Run All...   
  CALL SGDEDMGT.USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM( BLAHNO =>                       
  'xx#########00000####',  BLAHID => '0'  )   
  Return Code = 0 
  Output Parameter #2 (BLAHID) = <NULL>   
  Statement ran successfully   (141 ms)
```

I even tried the CALL with the simplest format, as follows and still receive the same result...

```
CALL SGDEDMGT.USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM(
  'xx#########00000####',?);
```

I just don't understand why I'm getting null for BLAHID.

Here is my stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM (
    IN BLAHNO CHAR(20),
    OUT BLAHID INTEGER 
    )   
    LANGUAGE SQL
P1 : BEGIN
    DECLARE TMPP INTEGER;
    SET TMPP = (
    SELECT BLAHID
        FROM SGDEDMGT.BLAHS
        WHERE "BlahNumber" = BLAHNO ) ;
    SET BLAHID = TMPP;   
END P1
```

Btw, in case anyone is wondering, I sanity checked by doing a simple SELECT WHERE just to be sure the test data I'm filtering for is actually there as a returnable value :)

Comment: Could you try to provide some reproducible example like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/L2dsu80y) one? The last statement doesn't throw an exception as expected...

Comment: You are calling the procedure with a constant `'0'`; instead, you should provide a variable that will be set upon the procedure return. How to do that depends on the client software you use.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Wow. I didn't know dbfiddle existed. I'm going to have to learn it when I get a break. What I saw in that link is basically THE reproducible example. It's about as close to the real thing as possible. Only difference is in the entity and column names and primary key is auto-generating, etc, trivial stuff.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for pointing that out. and I am aware of that. I came across an article that led me to try initializing the OUT param with a value. It didn't matter in my tests in RUN SQL SCRIPT. I will still get a null if it's a zero or a question mark.

Comment: Did you make a test to examine the behaviour of your code? For example, if the query in the stored procedure returns no rows? For example, try `SELECT COALESCE(blahid, -9999)...` or test for the no-rows-found sqlstate 100 and then set the TMPP variable to some value that indicates no rows found ? (This is in addition to making sure that you call the stored-procedure with a variable , not a constant, to receive the output parameter).

Answer (score 0):

In Run SQL Scripts, you simply pass a parameter marker, `?` , into the call statement for the output parm..

```
CALL SGDEDMGT.USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM(
  BLAHNO => 'xx#########00000####',  
  /* IN  CHARACTER(20)    */
  BLAHID => ?   /* OUT INTEGER          */
);

--with positional parms
CALL SGDEDMGT.USPGETBLAHIDFROMBLAHNUM('xx#########00000####', ?);
```

Comment: Been there done that. As I mentioned to mustaccio, I can pre-init the out param with a zero value or leave it as a question mark and I'll still get the null result. I just want to sanity check it everything in this tool before I start my code in C# to call the SP. Thanks anyway Charles.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. My fault for not really paying attention. In Line 9 of my Create Procedure example, "SELECT BLAHID" (Note, it's not the real column name and I apologize for being cryptic), the issue itself was BLAHID. It should've been BlahId and because the real column name is longer than 6 characters, it should be enclosed in double quotes like "BlahId". Why the RUN SQL SCRIPT tool nor post compilation revealed any error about the column name BLAHID not existing *is a serious wonder* which gave me the false sense of being accurate and thus, running around chasing my own tail. Thanks to everyone who spent some time in helping me try to figure out the problem. **Much appreciated!**

Comment: I suspect there was a warning message when you created the proc, should have been an error in the joblog when you tried to call it.  
Note that there's no requirement to use double quotes with a column name "longer than 6 characters".   The only time you need double quotes is if you've used them to name a column with mixed cased.  `MYLONGCOLUMN`, `mylongcolumn`, `MyLongColumn`  will all work when a column name is unquoted.  It's only if you created the column with quotes as `"ColA"`  that you'd always need them.